# SoundManager2 WaveFormData and PeakData returns 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, soundmanager2

i'm trying to setup the SoundManager2 with WaveFormData and PeakData.
i have enabled everything as per the docs but SM Object still returns 0 values even while a sound is playing. Any idea why ?

```
    soundManager.url = 'swf/';
    soundManager.flashVersion = 9;
    soundManager.useHTML5Audio = true;
    soundManager.debugMode = false;
    soundManager.useHighPerformance = true;
    soundManager.useFastPolling = true;
    soundManager.usePeakData = true;
    soundManager.useWaveformData = true;
    soundManager.useEqData = true;
```

[image: The image is the output of the WaveFormData Property and PeakData Property]

Any idea why this is happening ?

Answer (score 1):

```
    soundManager.url = 'swf/';
    soundManager.flashVersion = 9;
    soundManager.useHTML5Audio = true;
    soundManager.debugMode = false;
    soundManager.flash9Options.useWaveformData = true;
    soundManager.flash9Options.useEQData = true;
    soundManager.flash9Options.usePeakData = true;
    soundManager.preferFlash = true;
```

This did the trick :)

Comment: `useWaveformData` and `useEQData` are not really needed to get the peakData, also because they use very heavy processor load.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the peakData information, this configuration might help you:

```
soundManager.flash9Options = {
  usePeakData: true,      // enable left/right channel peak (level) data
  useWaveformData: false, // enable sound spectrum (May set CPUs on fire)
  useEQData: false,       // enable sound EQ (Also CPU-intensive)      
}
```

then make sure the `soundmanager` uses flash version 9:

```
soundManager.setup({
  url: '/soundmanager/swf/',
  flashVersion: 9, 
  // useHighPerformance: true,     
  preferFlash: true,      
  debugMode: true,
  onready: function() {},
});
```

This configuration loads [peakData](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/#sound-properties-flash9) in the sound Object